# What is the AMD/ATI Radeon 6000 series GPU architecture?

Tags: opencl, gpu, amd-processor

See question. I can find documentation on the 5000 series and 7000 series but no real notes on 6000 series. This is useful for trying to get close to the theoretical maximum throughput with OpenCL.

So far I've found [AMD's programming guide (pdf)](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/amdappsdk/assets/amd_accelerated_parallel_processing_opencl_programming_guide.pdf). This covers 5000 and 7000 series. But it only mentions 6000 series in passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the 6000 series gpus is that they are very similar to the 5000s, except for the 69xx, which are closer to the 7000s.

The 69xx gpus (Cayman) use a VLIW4 instruction set, the 6870 and lower models in the series use the VLIW5 architecture found in the 5000 gpus.

I found more about this on the wiki:

[Northern Islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Islands_%28GPU_family%29)

[AMD Graphic cards comparison (Northern Islands)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Northern_Islands_.28HD_6xxx.29_series)

Something else I have found useful is to google image search "amd X block diagram" where X is one of the following gpu code names: Cedar, Caicos, Turks, Juniper, Barts, Cayman, Antilles, etc.

Comment: Good info. Especially googling X block diagram. That is not something I have tried before. So this basically means for the lower 6000 series cards I should be treating as if they are 5000 series cards as far as architecture goes. I'll wait to accept for a day or so, pending others offering interesting answers. :)

Comment: I think you should be getting the info you need from available opencl calls -- clGetDeviceInfo being the main one. Unless you're really tweaking the kernels on a per device basis, you only need the basic info to make your kernel run correctly. If someone decides to run your app on an exotic FPGA card, it would still give a correct result.

Comment: One more suggestion is if you are trying to tweak specific to a AMD Platform, then you can use AMD Kernel Analyzer packaged along with the AMD APP SDK, in this you can drop down different h/w architecture like cayman, barts, turks etc and see how your ISA or IL for your kernle looks like on each of these architecture. I found  this too be very helpful.

Comment: Accepted this as it is the closest to answering the question. The answer (mostly a link) by ocluser is also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If youa are looking specifically for Cayman(6950/6970) architecture (VLIW 4) then look at the http://www.realworldtech.com/cayman

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The 6000s are basically the same as the 5000s. The only real significant difference is that Cayman is VLIW4 and the others in the series (e.g. Barts) are VLIW5 like the previous R600 architecture generations.